# Clear editText field wth drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have an autocomplete editText field and I found this code for clearing text on the editText field and also placing it on the right corner of the field, my problem is after I clear text once on the editText field the cross(drawable) disappears. I have to leave the page and come back again for it to be visible again. How can I make it visible all the time?Please help.
This is the code I have:

```
 String value = "";
    personAccountableAutoCompleteTextView.setText(value);
    final Drawable x = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clear);
    personAccountableAutoCompleteTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (personAccountableAutoCompleteTextView.getCompoundDrawables()[2] == null) {
                return false;
            }

            if (event.getX() > personAccountableAutoCompleteTextView.getWidth() - personAccountableAutoCompleteTextView.getPaddingRight() - x.getIntrinsicWidth()) {
                personAccountableAutoCompleteTextView.setText("");
                x.setVisible(true,true);
                personAccountableAutoCompleteTextView.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give yout edittext drawable right in xml like this:

```
<EditText
  android:layoutheight="wrap_content"
  android:layoutwidth="match_parent"
  android:drawableright="@drawable/yourimg"/>
```

and then give click listner to that drawable like this:

```
edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() >= (edittext.getRight() - edittext.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    // your action here

                 return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I got that part right, my problem is that the drawable disappears after I use it once, I cannot clear the EditText field twice.